# RJDBC Connection to Amazon Redshift in R

Tags: java, r, amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-s3

I tried to create JDBC connection with Amazon Redshift in R. Following the instruction under https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/connecting-r-with-amazon-redshift/, I created the following:

```
driver <- JDBC("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver", "RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.1.1001.jar", identifier.quote="`")

url <- "jdbc:redshift://xxxxxx.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com
:5439/user=xxx&password=xxx"

conn <- dbConnect(driver, url)
```

Everything works except that the last row gave me the error message of the following:

> Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
>     java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Error message not found: CONNECTION_REFUSED. Can't find bundle for base name com.amazon.dsi.core.impl.JDBCMessages, locale en

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I had the error but got it working. Things I did included :

1. used .jclassLoader()$setDebug(1L) to get full debug info of jar
   load  - this showed path it was checking
2. downloaded latest jar from amazon s3 (manually not with R)
3. moved the latest jar into the path that was being checked in a)
4. used real redshift instance being used by my team with good credentials

Voila it worked !